# Truncating leading digital numbers of a voltage

Tags: digital-logic, analog, adc

I would like to as if digitally sample a voltage value and then remove the leading digits in a voltage.

For example (truncating the 2 leading digits):

```
input voltage: 123.45V
output: 3.45V
```

But I don't want to implement anything too expensive or use an ADC. I want it to remain in the analog realm. Is there a way?

I know of a way of using an array of 20 transistors (or so) per digit to be truncated, but I happen, at the moment, to also need 6 of these "truncators". So I might as well use an ADC chip.

Comment: How expensive is "too expensive"?  How complicated is too complicated?

Comment: How can this be done in analog?I dont think opamps can perform digit shifting operations.

Comment: @vir this cannot be done in analog

Comment: Can't be done in analog? Figured as much.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "digitally sample" without the use of an ADC.  Can you be more descriptive?  Also, will those first digital *always* be 120V, or can that change?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I suspect this is a variation on the canonical [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Are you really in need of truncating digits, or are you assuming those digits will be "12" and trying to measure the excursion above 120?

Comment: Note this is a modulo operation, not digit shifting

Comment: also how many dollars does a microcontroller cost compared to 120 transistors?

Comment: It's an interesting question. Doesn't seem to lack clarity to me. Even if the endeavor is pointless, it's still a cool "circuit golf" problem.

Comment: Anything that uses discrete transistors would need to use very many of them, since individual transistors won't be precise enough to do the job. The job can be done with two quad comparators to form an ADC, a voltage reference, and some analog switches and trimmed resistors to form effectively a DAC, plus some op-amps to tie it all together. I will not be expensive, but making it accurate to 10mV for cheap requires manual trimming of probably a dozen trimmer potentiometers if not more. The potentiometers may well cost more than the rest of the circuit :)

Comment: *I know of a way of using an array of 20 transistors (or so) per digit to be truncated* Have you actually prototyped it and checked how it performs with regards to temperature sensitivity? Have you tried **touching any one of those transistors with your finger** for a couple seconds, and checked how it affects the output voltage?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array of comparators and voltage sources to suss out those first two digits, and subtract them in an analog fashion -- but I'm at a loss of what you mean by "digitally sample" in this context.

This would be sort of analogous to using the Course Flash ADC, and subtracting out result, then doing a final analysis of what remains by whatever method you choose.

See the description of the following figure in https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/8/810.html

[image: from Maxim doc]

Answer (score 0):

If displaying the deviation from 120 VAC using 7-segment LEDs and drivers, consider the following digital logic:

- Blank the hundreds digit always. Might be a good placeholder for a "+" and "-" symbol, see point 3.
- Blank the tens digit when it equals 2 *and* hundreds = 1.  Otherwise, subtract twenty from the real value and display that instead.
- Use the subtraction zero-crossing to indicate positive/negative.

This should result in a display of 120 VAC (implied) `±99.99` V.

Answer (score -1):

No this cannot be done in analog.Opamps can implement some math functions but not digit shifting.

Comment: There is a way, but having the array of transistors as I mentioned above is venturing to digital already.

Comment: Can you provide the link for the circuit which shifts digits to the left?

Comment: I've partially implemented it myself, but haven't I given away enough already on this site?

Comment: This isn't a site for sharing engineering riddles.  If you want the help, you need to put in details.  If you won't or can't, then hire someone and have them sign an NDA.